# MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup .. React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm developing a map application using React - Typescript - Leaflet
I've used ReactLeaflet package but when I'm using it I'm facing error while compiling issues
[image]

```
import * as React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
export default class MapsComp extends React.Component  {
render(){
    return(<div>asdf</div>)
} }
```

It would be helpful if any one can help me in rendering the map

Comment: Please include the text for the error rather than an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forked your project, made npm install and ran your code and the only thing is missing is `MapContainer`'s **height**. I did not get the error you are receiving. I am not sure why you get it.

On maps.tsx, `MapsComp` add `style={{ height: "100vh" }}` or whatever height suits your needs.

```
<MapContainer
        center={[51.505, -0.09]}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
>
...
</MapContainer>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

without any errors in the console.

Comment: Could u help me how can I dynamically add the Marker to the MapContainer

Comment: Please ask a new question and clarify the problem. Add dynamically the marker when? Give any further details and I will.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65625746/reactleaflet-add-multiple-marker

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your `tsconfig.json` file.

I am using the `react-leaflet` package with TypeScript too and this is my configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That is suppressing error and map is not rendering

Comment: There’s no map in your code...can you post your actual code and not a placeholder div?

Comment: find the git repo https://github.com/phanivaranasi/reactleafletmap