# How to add multiple markers using react-leaflet upon api call?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

In context to my previous question,
[MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup .. React Leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615254/mapcontainer-tilelayer-marker-popup-react-leaflet)

How can  I add multiple markers of places

Use case is that, when cycle is travelling from one place to other place, I need to show markets along the distance that bicycler has travelled.

Comment: Look at this [example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-popup-marker). You can define `Markers`  with `Popup` optionally as children of `MapContainer`

Comment: Yes! I have gone through it. But here, On every 5min I want to show the history of cycle trace on map. According to this use case I need to show the maker across the cycle locations

Comment: This is the information you should include in the description of your question. And where is your cycle trace data or locations? Please try to describe what you want to achieve and provide the necessary data/information you have so far not in messages but in the question description by editing your question.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Where are the cycle locations?

Comment: there will a embedded system which read geo location using SIM Card mobile data and using 4G network, I'm writing those coordinates into a database, and a service will read those data and result is kept in array format at client level, now in the react website  have to plot the coordinates which are retrieved from db.

Comment: So you will fetch the data and then you want to create markers according to that data.  I can give you an example with some mock data if this is what you want.

Comment: Sure, please share, if it solves in displaying the markers i'll modify code accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example. On `MapsComp`:

- Declare a state variable to keep track of the markers
- Fetch the markers when the comp mounts and save them to the variable
- Loop over the markers under `TileLayer` to visualize them when markers variable has data

  ```
   class MapsComp extends React.Component {
     state = { markers: [] };

     componentDidMount() {
       fetch("https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/?q=paris&type=street")
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
           this.setState({ markers: response.features });
         });
     }
   ...
   here loop overs markers data to visualzie them
   {this.state.markers.length > 0 &&
           this.state.markers.map((marker) => (
             <Marker
               position={[
                 marker.geometry.coordinates[1],
                 marker.geometry.coordinates[0]
               ]}
               icon={icon}
             >
               <Popup>{marker.properties.label}</Popup>
             </Marker>
           ))}
  }
  ```

Note that this is a free api used just for demonstrating the example.

**Edit**

I managed to reproduce your code.
you don't need a service to fetch the json because you have it **locally**. Just import it.

```
import json from "../data/data.json";
```

and then  assign it to the state variable (or even you could avoid that and use it directly, even better)

```
this.state = {
   geoData: json.Sheet1,
};
```

Inside `renderMarkers` method you have a dictionary so you need its values so use Object.values to extract the coordinates

```
renderMarkers = () => {
    let latLong: Array<Array<any>> = [];
    Object.values(this.state.geoData).map((val, index) => {
      let dt1: Array<any> = [];
      dt1.push(Number(val.lat), Number(val.lng));
      latLong.push(dt1);
    });
    return latLong;
  };
```

last but not least visualize the points as Circles and not as **Markers** use **preferCanvas** flag on map container because you have **26000** **markers**. Leaflet cannot handle such an amount of markers so render them as circle markers. You will still see that the performance is not the best but for sure better than using markers and not canvas.

I am not going to get into the reasons of this behavior as it is out of this questions' scope, as you have not mentioned that you have such a big amount of points in the first place.

```
 <MapContainer
          ...
          preferCanvas
  >
...
     {this.renderMarkers().length > 0 &&
                this.renderMarkers().map((value, index) => {
                  return (
                    <CircleMarker center={[value[1], value[0]]} key={index}>
                      <Popup>{index} Sydney, Hi!!!</Popup>
                    </CircleMarker>
                  );
     })}
```

This is the result of the rendering:

[image]

Comment: https://gist.github.com/phanivaranasi/e11111e4ca7c5412af7ccd61844d079b
Based upon your code, I've tried to render market but its not rendering here is the gist

Comment: I cannot run the code. Commit to your repo so I can reproduce it.